# How to optimize performance of iteration of a stream by preloading stream items in the background?

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance, linq

I have a situation where I need to process large number of files one by one on the UI thread, where both the loading of each file and the its processing can take a significant amount of time and combined they use too much memory too load all at once. This is all running in a .NET 4.8 application and, unfortunately, in a part of the code base that is synchronous.

In essence, my code looks like this:

```cs
IEnumerable<ScanFile> stream = GetScanFileStream();

foreach (ScanFile scanFile in scanFiles)
{
    Process(scanFile); // Requires to be called on the UI thread
}

IEnumerable<ScanFile> GetScanFileStream() =>
    from filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\scans", "*.json")
    select this.LoadScanFile(filePath); // I like to run this in the background
}
```

Both the the time it takes to execute `LoadScanFile` is roughly equivalent to the time it takes to execute `Process`, I'm, therefore, hoping to cut the time it takes to process these files in half by pre-loading the next file on a background thread while the operation is still running on the UI thread.

What I tried was to create a special `IEnumerable<T>` decorator implementation, wrapping the original stream, which allowed this behavior, but I quickly found out that the implementation got quickly too complex. I was starting using semaphores to synchronize between the thread. That's when I stopped pursuing this solution thinking there should be easier solutions that have the same effect.

I expected this behavior to be achievable using LINQ to parallel making use of constructs build-in to the BCL and the CLR, but an extensive Google search didn't yield any good results.

What solution could you advise that allows me to cut processing time in half?

Comment: you can use Parallel.ForEach(... or list.AsParralel().ForAll to increase performance.

Comment: @PowerMouse: Keep in mind that execution of the `Process` method must happen on the UI thread.

Comment: You don't have to do anything special, Parallel.Foreach() will wait until all its branched tasks are complete. or do await Parallel.ForEachAsync() ...

Comment: @PowerMouse: Would you be willing to post an answer showing an example using `Parallel.ForEach` suiting the requirements specified in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IAsyncEnumerable`, and make `LoadScanFile` async (either using async functions or using `Task.Run`). Then call the next task before yielding the previoous one.

```cs
IAsyncEnumerable<ScanFile> GetScanFileStream()
{
    ScanFile scanFile = null;
    foreach (var filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\scans", "*.json"))
    {
        // start the next task
        var scanFileTask = this.LoadScanFileAync(filePath);
        // if we have one already yield it
        if (scanFile != null)
            yield return scanFile;

        scanFile = await scanFileTask;
    }
    if (scanFile != null)    // and yield the last one also
        yield return scanFile;
}
```

Now you can do

```cs
await foreach (ScanFile scanFile in scanFiles)
{
    Process(scanFile); // Requires to be called on the UI thread
}
```

Comment: That's really elegant.

Answer (score 1):

as requested.
Option 1 Parallel.ForEach..

```
void Main()
{
    ConcurrentBag<ScanFile> resultCollection = new ConcurrentBag<ScanFile>();
    
    var options = new ParallelOptions();
    options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Math.Max(Environment.ProcessorCount / 2, 1)*10;
    
    ParallelLoopResult result =
        Parallel.ForEach(
            Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\1", "*.json").ToList(),
            options, filePath =>
            {
                resultCollection.Add(this.LoadScanFileAync(filePath));
            });
    
    result.Dump();
    resultCollection.Dump();
}
```

[image]

Option 2 : check `Task.WhenAll()` so process will wait until all tasks are done
kind of:

```
ConcurrentBag<ScanFile> resultCollection {get;set;}

void Main()
{
    resultCollection = new ConcurrentBag<ScanFile>();
    DoAllAsync().Dump();
    resultCollection.Dump();
}

public Task DoAllAsync() =>
    Task.WhenAll(Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\1", "*.json")
        .Select(filePath => Task.Run(() => 
            resultCollection.Add(this.LoadScanFileAync(filePath)))));
```

[image]

as an option 3 you can use `.AsParallel()`:

```
resultCollection = new ConcurrentBag<ScanFile>();

Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\1", "*.json").ToList()
    .AsParallel()
    .ForAll(filePath => resultCollection.Add(this.LoadScanFileAync(filePath)));

resultCollection.Dump();
```

P.S. you can simply test by add a

```cs
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds((5)));
```

to LoadScanFileAync() fuction

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide me with these options. Much appreciated.